# BLE estimote eddystone background task not running

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy, estimote, windows-10-universal, eddystone

I'm trying to create a background task that will be run when the system detects an eddystone advertisement broadcasted by an estimote beacon.

I already configured the beacon to send eddystone packets and I used `UniversalBeaconLibrary` to get these packets while the application is in the foreground (no problems here).

Now I want to get a notification while the application is not launched (using a background task reacting to bluetooth broadcasted packets). To my understanding, to avoid putting to much strain on the battery/cpu, I do need to filter these advertisements.

One of the simplest form of filtering (the one I tried to use) is by using the company id given by the Bluetooth SIG.

Here is what I tried :

```
public static async void Register()
{
    if (BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Count == 0)
    {
        var trigger = MakeTrigger();

        // this is needed for Phone, not so for Windows in this case.  
        var allowed = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        if ((allowed != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied) &&
            (allowed != BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified))
        {
            BackgroundTaskBuilder builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder
            {
                Name = "BLEWatcher",
                TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BLEBackgroundConsumer.Consumer).FullName
            };
            builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
            builder.Register();
        }
    }
}
private static BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger MakeTrigger()
{
    var trigger = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger();
    //Can add some filters here
    //trigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(new BluetoothLEManufacturerData()
    //{
    //    CompanyId = 349 //Estimote
    //});
    //trigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(new BluetoothLEManufacturerData()
    //{
    //    CompanyId = 76 // Apple
    //});
    //trigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(new BluetoothLEManufacturerData()
    //{
    //    CompanyId = 224 // Google
    //});
    return (trigger);
}
```

As it is I get an exception, saying that there is not enough or too much filtering.

When uncommenting one of the trigger blocks, I got no exception but the task does not seem to launch.

**EDIT : ** I asked estimote what was the Company Id they were boradcasting when using eddystone packets. And according to them there is none.

In regard of this answer, what would be a suitable filter ?

Answer (score 1):

A Bluetooth SIG company id is only used with a manufacturer Bluetooth LE advertisement, like iBeacon and AltBeacon.  Eddystone uses service Bluetooth LE advertisements, which don't contain a company id.  Instead, they contain a 16-bit Service UUID of 0xFEAA.

See here for more details:  https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/protocol-specification.md

Comment: Thanks, now I just have to create a Bitmask for this Service UUID.